# setTimeout in callback to reset state

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use `setTimeout` in a callback to reset the state after a few seconds, but get the error **Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function**

Can anyone please help?

```
setMainState: function() {
    this.setState({
        clicked: !this.state.clicked
    }, this.delayState());
},

delayState: function() {
    setTimeout((function() {
        this.setState({
            clicked: false
        }), 2000}));
},

handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setMainState();
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because `this` in `setTimeout` callback does not refer to your Component object, you need set `this` by yourself with [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.setState({
    clicked: false
  })
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

or if you use `ES2015`, you can use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    clicked: false
  })
}, 2000);
```

Comment: An important detail here is that "old-school" function declarations have different rules about `this` than arrow functions (as this answer implicitly shows - I just think it is worth pointing out).

Answer (score 1):

Context of this is being change in setTimeout function so you need take a variable to store that object `self` and then it will be same in that function

```
setMainState: function() {
    this.setState({
        clicked: !this.state.clicked
    }, this.delayState());
},

delayState: function() {
 var self = this;
    setTimeout((function() {
        self.setState({
            clicked: false
        }), 2000}));
},

handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setMainState();
},
```